# Using a Neural Network to Predict ODE Output Given the Initial Condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say we have a system of ODE's that describe how X affects Y:

> dXdt = -k * X
>
> dYdt = Kin * (1 - (Vmax * X)/(Km + X)) - kout * Y

I am trying to use a neural network to input `X(0)`, `Y(0)`, and `t`, and output `Y(t)`. I made a feed-forward network in TensorFlow, and trained it on data generated with the above equations, using Y data generated with the initial value of X being 5 and 10. The initial value of Y I left constant, using its steady-state value (the value where dYdt = 0 and X = 0). For testing, I tried initial X values in-between and outside of two values I trained with. For all testing, Y(0) was left the same.

The testing results for in-between values are very good, and the results for the outside values are pretty good as well. However, this is only over the time period that the network was trained over, say t=[0,10]. Once I try to predict a value past this time period, the predictions start to drift off.

Is there a better method of implementing the network so that I can predict the values past the training interval? Ideally, I'd like to be able to predict the return of Y to steady-state, once X has reached 0. I've been reading about using RNNs, however I need it to be trained on sparse data, where the time points aren't evenly spaced. The network I used above was able to do this, at least for the trained interval. Also, most examples of RNNs that I've seen (that aren't for language processing) rely on predicting future time points based on the previous time points, instead of in the way that I am trying to use it.

An idea I have would be to use my original network to predict the values over the trained time range (and a lot of them to create a rich data-set), and then feed that into an RNN to predict the values past the time range. Would this be a feasible idea, or are there some other methods that I could try that would work better.

Comment: Why are you using a neural network for this in the first place?

Comment: The idea is that for a more complicated system, with multiple Y's, where the interactions are unknown, a neural network can be used instead of guessing at what the ODE's should look like.

Comment: Why not use the appropriate numerical methods?

Comment: Because we can't solve an ODE if we don't have an ODE to solve.